# Sequential tagged queue processing

Tags: python, rabbitmq, apache-kafka, microservices, messagebroker

I have a queue of tagged messages:

tail-2-3-1-1-2-1-head

and I have n workers, for example 2: A and B.

I need a sequential processing for different tags.

For example, if A take 1, than B can take next message 2, but if B ends processing befor A, B can't take another 1 message, it should take 3, becouse A alredy processing 1, and second 1 message could be ready before first - it's incorrect.

Thank you for comments.

Comment: A simple de-queue should meet your requirements, from what i understand.

Comment: I would make you of shared list between your threads. This means one list that tells the threads what to be calculated and an other list that tells the threads what is calculated.

Comment: For more info I can explain it in the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138143/multiprocessing

Comment: J. Goedhart, sorry, can't talk in chat: You must have 20 reputation

Comment: any solution to this question?